# Postgres - date index for reading dates before or after (<, <=, >, >=)

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am having trouble with my date index when my condition is either before or after a given date.
Using operators (<, <=, >, >=).

My table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE date_playground
(
  id          BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
  due_date    date        NOT NULL,

  primary key (id)
);
```

And my index is

```
CREATE INDEX date_playground_idx_due_date
ON date_playground (due_date);
```

When my query is

```
-- SAMPLE  1 
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  *
FROM  date_playground
WHERE due_date = '2019-09-07' :: DATE;
```

This uses the index

```
QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using date_playground_idx_due_date on date_playground  (cost=0.42..279.73 rows=75 width=287) (actual time=0.043..0.071 rows=10 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (due_date = '2019-09-07'::date)
Planning Time: 0.636 ms
Execution Time: 0.140 ms
```

However when I use the stated operators - **<, <=, >, >=**

```
-- SAMPLE 2
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  *
FROM  ln.amortization_schedule_active a
WHERE due_date <= '2019-09-07' :: DATE;

QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on date_playground  (cost=0.00..35133.86 rows=396944 width=287) (actual time=0.032..443.417 rows=404839 loops=1)
  Filter: (due_date <= '2019-09-07'::date)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 331870
Planning Time: 0.437 ms
Execution Time: 483.891 ms
```

It never uses the index, it always performs a full scan.

Can anyone suggest how can I optimize the second query?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not full scan, this is range scan, equal operator will do a unique scan

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ so if that's the case, this is expected? Is there some way that I could improve the second query?

Comment: yes this is expected behavior, you might check this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236970/creating-index-on-timestamp-column-to-use-with-range-operators

Comment: Try running vacuum again and if postgres sticks to using the same plan as you've mentioned for the second query, then postgres is already choosing the best plan. You can observe that by forcing postgres to use index scan by disabling sequential scan. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-query.html

Comment: The second query returns about half of the rows of the table. A index lookup would be slower than a Seq Scan

Comment: Not quite exactly the same, but very similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-make-postgres-use-an-index-when-using-in-or-any/253116#253116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL *could* use the index in your second query, but it correctly chooses not to do that because it would be inefficient.

For a query that selects half the rows in the table, a sequential scan is more efficient than an index scan: The index scan would have to visit most of the table blocks anyway, so why bother with random I/O or building a bitmap?

Comment: No I understand, I tried changing the date (close to `MIN(due_date)`) and it used the index.